# Usage access settings, permissions

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to use UsageStatsManager. I know that I am supposed to include.
`<user-permission android:label="PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>`.

I also started an intent for the user to allow usage access.
 `Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
 startActivity(intent);`

But my app does not show up in the **Apps with usage access** list in the settings.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5Vhx.png)

I need to know why my app is not showing up in that list?

Comment: I'm having (suddenly) the same issue - strange, because it worked before (app was listed there). Did you solve it in the meantime somehow?

Comment: no , i did not. My project allowed a work around so i did not continue with this method.

Answer (score 0):

Your tag is misspelled. its supposed to be `<uses-permission/>` instead of `<user-permission/>` RIP